# Обновление данных в MySQL средствами PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysql

Добрый день! 
Мне нужно обновить данные таблицы т.е. я в таблицу вывожу большое количество данных и некоторые из них мне нужно изменять. Моя вьюшка

```
<form action="<?= site_url('pages/update_status_wagon')?>" method="post">
 <? foreach ($status as $vagon): ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?= $vagon->number_vagona ?></td>
                            <td><input id="sobstvenik" name="sobstvenik[]" value="<?= $vagon->sobstvenik ?>"/></td>
                            <td><input id="arendator" name="arendato[]r" value="<?= $vagon->arendator ?>"/></td>
                            <td><input id="napravlenie" name="napravlenie[]" value="<?= $vagon->napravlenie ?>"/></td>
                            <td><input id="comment" name="comment[]" value="<?= $vagon->comment ?>"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <? endforeach; ?>
    </form>
```

Моя модель

```
public function update_vagon_status($data, $id) // обновление данных вагон статус
    {
      $query = $this->db->update('vagon_status', $data, array('id' => $id));
      return $query->result_array();
    }
```

Мой контроллер

```
public function update_status_wagon () // Обновление данных в таблице вагон статус, меню (статус вагона)
    {
           $id = $this->input->post('id');
           $sobstvenik = $this->input->post('sobstvenik');
           $arendator = $this->input->post('arendator');
           $napravlenie = $this->input->post('napravlenie');
           $comment = $this->input->post('comment');
           $data['query'] = $this->Unload_model->update_vagon_status($data, $id);
           redirect('pages/status_wagona');
    }
```

Понимаю, что написан полный бред)) Только недавно стала изучать ООП и фреймворки. И ладу не могу им дать. Помогите исправить обновление данных. у меня вся проблема в том, что я знаю как, к примеру, работать с одной записью, отправить ее на редактирование, а как работать с большим количеством - не знаю.
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первый вопрос ко view - что за переменные $status и $vagon (судя по всему, $status - массив объектов $vagon ? не очень понятно, приведите структуру)
Дальше: на форме нет поля id, которое считывается в контроллере

```
$id = $this->input->post('id');
```

Я так понимаю, форма - список вагонов, свойства которых можно изменять, следовательно каждый вагон контроллер должен идентифицировать и найти его свойства. Имена полей формы типа sobstvenik[] значат, что на сервер данные придут в массиве с числовыми ключами (0,1,2...) Это не очень подходит, сделайте как-то так:

```
name="sobstvenik[<?=$vagon->id?>]"
```

(для всех полей формы).
Тогда в контроллере при чтении переменных, например:

```
$sobstvenik = $this->input->post('sobstvenik');
```

будет возвращаться ассоциативный массив '{ID вагона}' => '{Значение его собственника}'

```
$data['query'] = $this->Unload_model->update_vagon_status($data, $id);
```

Переменная $data в качестве первого параметра не определена вообще. В принципе, если отталкиваться от того, что update_vagon_status - метод для апдейта одного вагона, то необходимо в цикле перебирать все вагоны, и для каждого вызывать update_vagon_status

Comment: $status и $vagon - это вывод данных из таблицы. т.е. грубо говоря у меня формируется таблица из 300 строк в которую можно вносить изменения.